# Ksqldb date parsing from integer

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have a KSQLDB stream from a topic using SQL Server CDC Debezium connector that has a column which stores the date in integer format like this:

## Stream

```
Df
---
1210813
```

In Sql Server T-SQL, I can do the following and extract the date:

```
Select TRY_CAST(RIGHT(df, 6) as datetime) from datacon;
```

## Output:

2021-08-13 00:00:00.000

I tried to cast this in KSQLDB using the below scalar functions:

```
 select stringtodate(substring(cast(df as string), 2), 'yy-mm-dd') from datcon emit changes;
```

But this results in a null.

Also, for some reason when I try to use functions *format_date, parse_date* from the doc => https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/ksqldb-reference/scalar-functions/#parse_date, I get the below error:

```
Can't find any functions with the name 'FORMAT_DATE'
Can't find any functions with the name 'PARSE_DATE'
```

Is there any other way I can extract the date from the above format of date.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unclear what version of ksql you're running, but your format is wrong. Did you mean `yyyy-MM-dd`? And did you want to grab all 10 characters?

Comment: @OneCricketeer so in the given value 1210813, I only want to pick the 6 characters from the right, so I did a substring, which will be of the date format => 21-08-13. I tried giving the format as 'yyyy-MM-dd' but it too brings the output as null. The ksqldb-server version I have is 0.20.0 running from a docker container.

Comment: And ksql-cli version 0.20.0

Comment: What is the server version, not the CLI? That is where date functions would be available or not... Sorry, its hard to tell what "output" you are showing. But `substring(cast(df as string), 2)` would only give you `10813` if `df` is `1210813`, and that **doesn't match** `yy-mm-dd` or `yyyy-MM-dd` (note: month **is uppercase**), and thus gives you nulls

Comment: @OneCricketeer ksqldb-server version is 0.20.0. I ran the substring without the date conversion function and here is the output:
ksql> select substring(cast(df as string), 2)  from datcon emit changes;

|KSQL_COL_0                                                                                                                                                   

|210813

Comment: Just to clarify, the output of **substring(cast(df as string),2)** is **210813**. Now if I go ahead and use **stringtodate(substring(cast(df as string),2), 'yy-MM-dd')** I still get the output as **null**. Should I be using some other function apart from stringtodate?

Comment: Like I said, `210813` contains no dashes, so unclear why you think `yy-mm-dd` would work compared to `yyMMdd`. And again, `mm` is minutes, not a month - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html